# javascript trap for null from MS Access

Tags: javascript, ms-access, null

This should be simple but...
I'm populating a few select boxes with values from MS Access db via JavaScript.  So... I loop through the records and retrieve names.  Some of these are valid, some are empty, and some are null (for whatever reason).  I want to trap the empty and null values so they don't show up in the select options.  Here's what I have:

```
var SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT design_lead FROM projects";
rs.Open(SQL, cn);
    if(!rs.bof) {
        rs.MoveFirst();
    }
var i=0;
while(!rs.eof) {
    desLead = rs("design_lead");
    if(desLead==null || desLead==undefined || desLead=='') {
        i=i+1;
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
    else {
        $("#leadName").append("<option>"+desLead+"</option>")
        i=i+1;
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
}
rs.Close();
```

Problem is that null always shows up in the options list.  I've searched for a few days but have not found anything that helps... and I've tried many different traps (typeof, etc.) but nothing works.

Comment: Are you sure the value is `null` and not `"null"`?

Answer (score 1):

How about just not returning the null values in the first place:

```
var SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT design_lead FROM projects WHERE design_lead IS NOT NULL";
```

Also, you can shrink your while loop down a bit, given that there's only one line different in the if and else cases:

```
while(!rs.eof) {
    desLead = rs("design_lead");
    if(desLead) {
        $("#leadName").append("<option>"+desLead+"</option>")
    }
    i=i+1;
    rs.MoveNext();
}
```

By saying `if(desLead)` you are testing if `desLead` is "truthy", noting that `null`, `undefined` and the empty string are all "falsy".

If the actual string `"null"` might be returned for some reason then just do:

```
if(desLead && desLead != "null")
```